# Are unbranded home security camera secure?

Tags: physical, risk-analysis, threat-modeling

I plan on buying a couple of cheap cameras for my home. I plan to put them just inside the doors like the laundry door, I won't be putting them in the bedroom or living room.

My major concern is how secure are they ? Can it be used to hack my wifi or devices on my network ? Is there a possibility of a backdoor where someone can see the video ?

These cameras are made in china. (*I'm not being racist to chinese but there have been reports of some unbranded Chinese products that hack your wifi*)

Here's an example of a camera: https://www.mydeal.com.au/wireless-1080p-hd-security-camera

Comment: What makes you think branded security cameras are secure? Default credentials, hidden backdoors, vulnerable services, accessible cloud stored content are all issues people have found in branded solutions in the past.

Comment: @wireghoul fair point

Comment: Who asked for product recommendations ??  This is a valid information security question ... whoever marked this as onhold, please read the question !!

Answer (score 1):

> My major concern is how secure are they?

Probably not very secure at all. Why would a cheap no-name wifi-web-cam be secure? The main development time/energy/money probably went into creating the desired functionality with little regard for security.

> Can it be used to hack my wifi or devices on my network?

Sure, it's always a *possibility*. Whether or not this occurrence is *likely* depends on what you mean by "hack" as well as the unknown specifics of the camera such as the platform, the os, the applications, the infrastructure, etc.

Comment: While I tend to agree with you, pretty hard to make generalizations about unknown brands, I believe it is a case by case basis. Who knows, a highly secure camera might be their niche

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not their niche. Also, who are "they," if it's an unbranded camera there's no accountability. Also, even known brands don't tend to give two cents about security. So, I'm feeling very confident this cheap camera is no different.

Comment: Exactly. You are making assumptions about something you have no information on. There is accountability, you had to buy the camera from somewhere... you don’t install cameras dropped on your doorstep

Comment: @pm1391 Speaking from experience, these things tend to have extremely weak root passwords that can be used with telnet, and even if only port 80 is accessible vulnerabilities aren't hard to find. That's how Mirai got so big.